# Storing two hashes of same password?

Tags: passwords, hash, salt

Typically for user passwords we store their hashes and salt alongside in the database - one per user.

I wonder the security implications of hashing the same password twice and storing locally both.

```
hash(pwd, salt1)  # => $digest1$salt1
hash(pwd, salt2)  # => $digest2$salt2
```

Would storing these two in the same database make it easier for an attacker to figure out the password? Does it matter if the 2nd hashing uses salt1 or salt2?

The use-case for this is that I want to use the 2nd hash as an encryption key for user's secrets.

Comment: If you use the same salt, then for the same password you will obtain the same hash.

Comment: What is the purpose of storing two hashes of the same password ?

Comment: @elsadek the second hash is used as an encryption key

Comment: How then do you deal with the case when the user changes their password? Do you decrypt and re-encrypt all secrets before the password change is completed? It makes no sense to have ephemeral, user-supplied input as a key.

Comment: @schroeder that's the idea. The reason is that only the user should be allowed to decrypt the secrets (when they provide their password)

Comment: That's a bad idea. There are much better ways to accomplish your goal. Don't do it this way. Keep the key separate from the password. Protect the key with the password. Don't protect data directly by the password. Check out how design patterns by LastPass, etc. work where the keys are only usable by end users.

Comment: OP, I agree with @schroeder.  This is not a zero-trust system, as your system would see the user's password in plaintext (after it is sent through the TLS tunnel) when the user logs in, and therefore, your system would have everything it needs to access the user's secrets.   Instead, you might want to look at SRP protocol See protonmail.com/blog/encrypted_email_authentication for an interesting read on how ProtonMail authenticates the user, without knowledge of the user's password, where the user also ends up with a key for encrypting their secrets as well during the process.

Comment: If you plan to use hash #2 as a secret key then you are literally storing a user's secret key in your database as cleartext. Have you thought this through?

Comment: @JohnWu it's essentially a DEK which then is encryptet with a KEK. The significant implementation detail is that the DEK is a hash of the password in my design, with the idea that in that way only the user can derive the key when they log in

Comment: If you are planning to use the value as an encryption key then it should not be stored or sent together with the encrypted data. That would make the encryption useless as any potential attacker would likely get access both if they were compromised.

Answer (score 3):

If proper salts are used then there are no security implications in this case.
In fact, for bigger system this will be a rather common occurrence as there will be multiple users having the same P@ssw0rd!.

It requires that the salts are cryptographically random and only ever used once. So the second hashing **must not** reuse the salt that was used for the first hashing.

Comment: My web credentials are a little out of date but I thought adding the username to the hashing operation was a mitigation for accidental common password/salt.